# Запятая перед словом "почему" (2)

Tags: запятые, правила, придаточное-предложение

Есть предложение:

***Он не знал, почему всё так сложилось, но был уверен, что это правильно.***

В предложении выше всё понятно. Но как поступать с запятой перед "почему" в таком случае?

***Он не знал"," почему, но был уверен, что это правильно.***

Или вовсе в таком?

***Он не знал"," почему.***

Ставить в последних двух предложениях запятую перед "почему" или не ставить? Хочется знать, есть ли точное правило на подобное или данное расплывчато: мол, если настаиваете, то всё можно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Он не знал  почему, но был уверен, что это правильно. Он не знал почему.**

Это правило рассмотрено у Розенталя http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137

4. Между главной и следующей за ней придаточной частью сложноподчиненного предложения запятая не ставится:

3) если придаточная часть состоит из одного союзного слова (относительного местоимения или наречия): **Я бы тоже желал знать почему** (Л. Т.); Не знаю почему, но я его не понимал (Триф.);

В условиях контекста возможна постановка запятой или тире и перед одиночным союзным словом: **Что же** надо делать? **Научите, что** — усиленное логическое выделение местоимения; Одно время он что-то шептал, не могли понять — что? (А. Т.) — постановка тире подчеркивает значение местоимения и оправдывается вопросительной интонацией.